# loop thought each object and get name and value

Tags: jquery

```
var json = {};    

object.prototype._storeMap = function (property_name, value){
      this.json = json;
      // Save src to json object
      this.json[property_name] = {
        objectStyle: value
      };
      return;
    }
```

i use this to store data into my object , how i make a function to loop thought each object and get the property name and the value ?

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    sum += value;
});
```

something function like this ?

```
  for (var prop in this.json){
    if (that.json.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
     passdata(prop);
    }
  }
```

i was using this to get data before but i dont know why it somehow cause problem to my code any one can explain to me ?

object data

```
display-image1:Object
objectImage:"1"
```

Comment: can you please explain what will be your json structure?

Comment: Can you give an example, what is your input and expected output?

Comment: i edit the post , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to print object keys and there value. 
You can do like this. I am showing you a example here print object keys, object and object value.

```js
var data = [{
  a : "aa",
        b : "bb"
 }
];

for(var i in data){
 console.log(Object.keys(data[i]));  // Get keys of objects
  console.log(data[i]);               // Print the object
  console.log(data[i].a)              // Print value one by one
}
```